# Boxing, how much to rotate body on Cross Punch?

Tags: boxing, mixed-martial-arts, muay-thai

How much should a person's torso rotate on cross right hand punch? Generally, on orthodox stance, person's body start angled at 4:00 on clock. When doing cross punch with right hand, I rotate my rear leg forward and torso at 3:00, so I am standing straight forward ahead. Many boxing coaches are saying I should overrotate torso at 2:00 or 1:00. Is that true? This would mean the torso would not be pointing as same direction of back foot.

Body Direction:

[image]

Appendix Footwork:

[image]

Straight punch examples with Right Hand:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm interested to know how you would answer your own question (You're allowed to do so here). If you take into consideration the principles discussed in relation to your other questions (basic biomechanics/range/variety/power/speed/balance etc), you might find that you already have the foundations of a good answer. Others will still likely provide answers too, but it could prove useful. If this sounds condescending, I sincerely apologise. It's just that I learned (and continue to learn) a lot from analysing my own skills and combining these insights with lessons from others.

Comment: no problem, I am guessing it all depends, I generally use Stack overflow as gauge of consensus on a message board, and justifications to variety schools of thought, this one is intriguing , because that is what my excellent Muay thai coach was teaching me today @Futilitarian

Comment: maybe the answer depends between Muay thai, boxing, and mma, not sure either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much you rotate depends largely upon how much you *need* to rotate in order to reach your opponent.

The ideal range would allow you to rotate beyond square - or 90 degrees - to approximately 135 degrees, as the greater the rotation, the greater the potential force of your punch. This also allows helps you achieve the boxing ideal of 'hitting without being hit', as you maximise your distance from your opponent.

Incorporate torso rotation into almost every punch, rather than relying upon the much weaker combination of shoulder and arm muscles alone. Even a slight twist, when performed correctly, will add considerable force to your strikes. Although torso rotation may seem less important when throwing feints and soft, distracting shots, consistency of torso/shoulder rotation will make various punches harder to read.

Two tips:

1. Avoid leaning forward to reach your opponent. Rely instead on torso rotation. If you lean forward, you place too much weight upon your front foot which reduces your ability to regain a defensively responsible stance and leaves your head very vulnerable to counters. Using rotation to achieve the required reach will instil your punches with greater and more balanced power.
2. When sparring, contact is (or should be) substantially lighter than in a real fight. As a consequence, when sparring, boxers tend to execute punches that barely reach their opponent; that merely tap them. The downside to this is that, during a fight, you want to punch *through* you target, which requires a different estimation of range. You generally fight as you train, so if when sparring your punches always end the instant leather touches flesh, you risk throwing ineffective punches during a bout.  To help prevent this, you can practice punching through the target when doing pad work and bag work, and practice pulling your punches in sparring; by getting slightly closer to your opponent so that you always have an extra fist's distance in reserve. This habit will also help reduce your miss count, as you will have created additional margin for error.

Mayweather routinely showed fullish rotation when he employed his [pull counter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRP0YZwzo0g). It's an awesome technique to have in your arsenal, but it takes excellent torso flexibility and strength, and immaculate timing. You also run the risk of being countered by a left (and right) hook, and even Mayweather's defence falls short in this regard (see 2:00).